# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://history.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I'm kind of amused by a moderator election with 4 slots open and 4 candidates running. What's the point of actually holding the election when all 4 candidates are guaranteed to win it? - haha

Answer (score 5):

If we are allowed to reply to this: I've scaled my participation way back but I'd like to thank all of the current mods for their diligent efforts over the years.

Thank you!
Korvin